# How to seperate words with quotes

Tags: awk, sed, command-line

I am working on a data set of cars; the cars make and model are displayed in a string like below. You can assume the model is only one word.

```
"Honda civic LX" 
"audi 500s (diesel)"
"toyota camry" 
"ford ranger"
```

My desired output is to have the make (which consists in a single word) in single quotes, while the model and trim are in their own single quotes, like below:

```
'honda' 'civic LX'
'audi' '500s (diesel)'
'toyota' 'camry' 
'ford' 'ranger'
```

I should also note the data set im working with is organized as such.

```
28.0   4   119   82.0   2720   99   1        "audi 500s (diesel)"
23.5   4   225   76.0   5530   81   1        "toyota camry"
```

I want to solve it with SED and i got close to solving it by the following command.

```
sed "s/\"/'/g;s/ /' '/"
```

However, That makes my data set look like the below. You can see it adds a ' ' at the end of the first column which isnt what i want. Also, I thought the command would seperate make and model but it doesnt.

```
28.0' '  4   119   82.0   2720   99   1        'audi 500s (diesel)'
23.5' '  4   225   76.0   5530   81   1        'toyota camry'
```

Comment: `sed -E 's/"([^" ]+) +([^"]+)"$/'"'\1' '\2'/"`

Comment: `awk -F\" -v q=\' '{sub(/ /,q" "q,$2);$2=q$2q}1'`

Comment: @jhnc Thank you ! Do you mind breaking down the SED command?

Comment: Other than slightly cryptic escaping for the single/double-quotes, it's just a simple `s///` command. See: https://regex101.com/r/pMjctB/1

Comment: @jhnc Thanks a ton. the link you provided is really helpful and i will definitely use it in the future!

Answer (score 2):

Hope this works.

```
sed "s/\"/'/g"| sed -E "s/([a-z])( )/\1' '/"
```

**Explanation**

The first part(or the 'find' part) `([a-z])( )` finds the occurrence of a lower-case alphabet followed by a space into 2 groups, which is denoted by the `()`. So, the first group is the alphabet `([a-z])` and the second group is the space `( )`.

In the second part(or the replace part) `\1' '`, `\1` denotes the first group which is found (This is back-reference, and for this to work, the -E flag is essential). If we didn't do this, the alphabet and the space, both will be replaced by `' '`, so we'll lose the last alphabet, which will result in something like `aud' '500s (diesel)'`. To retain the last alphabet, I had to do that.

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot. Do you mind breaking down the second expression?               "sed -E "s/([a-z])( )/\1' '/"  "

Answer (score 1):

I would go with `awk` on this one(which gives us more easiness in terms of functions and their usage), in case you are ok with it. Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v s1="\047" '
match($0,/"[^"]*"/){
  if(RSTART>1){
     printf("%s ",substr($0,1,RSTART-1))
  }
  matched=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  num=split(matched,arr," ")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    gsub(/"/,"",arr[i])
    val=(val?val OFS:"") (s1 arr[i] s1)
  }
  printf("%s%s\n",val,(RSTART+RLENGTH)<length($0)?substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1):"")
  val=""
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -v s1="\047" '                            ##Starting awk program from here and creating variable s1 which has single quote in it as a value.
match($0,/"[^"]*"/){                          ##Using match function to match from " to till " here.
  if(RSTART>1){                               ##If RSTART is greater than 1 then do following.
     printf("%s ",substr($0,1,RSTART-1))      ##Printing string sub string of current line from 1 to RSTART-1 here.
  }
  matched=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)           ##Creating matched variable which has regex matched value here.
  num=split(matched,arr," ")                  ##Splitting matched into arr with delimiter of space.
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){                        ##Running a loop from i=1 to till num value which has number of elements in arr value in it(taken above).
    gsub(/"/,"",arr[i])                       ##Globally substituting " with NULL in arr value here.
    val=(val?val OFS:"") (s1 arr[i] s1)       ##Creating val which has current value of arr wrapped in s1 and keep appending its value to it.
  }
  printf("%s%s\n",val,((RSTART+RLENGTH)<length($0)?substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1):"")) ##Printing val and rest of line here.
  val=""                                      ##Nullifying val here.
}
' Input_file                                  ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```